# Gmail SMTP server has stopped sending emails after I rebooted it

Tags: python, flask, smtp

I have tried to use flask_mail to send emails via gmail SMTP. I want to simply send an email back to the host with some details.

I have set the following settings

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'fakeemail@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'fakepassword'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
```

And wrote the following code to send

```
def send_email(senders_email, senders_subject, senders_feedback):
    print("email " + senders_email)
    print("sub " + senders_subject)
    print("feed " + senders_feedback)
    msg = Message('Feedback from ' + senders_email, sender='fakeemail@gmail.com',
                  recipients=['fakeemail@gmail.com'])
    print("message defined")
    msg.body = "Users Subject: " + senders_subject + "\n" + "Users Feedback: " + senders_feedback
    print("body set")
    mail.send(msg)
    print("message sent")
```

At first I was getting successful emails which sent the specific email to me but now I get a 500 error after about 20 or 30 seconds

```
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This error just says this is a network issue. It's not caused by any error in your script. Please check your network connection, make sure you can access `smtp.gmail.com` host  and there is no firewall blocking your connections.

Comment: I cannot find anything about it being down. The page google has to help doesnt do much either: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: Please be preciese. Did you receive OSError 101 or 500 error from SMTP server? What you write is not the same of the exception message you pasted. Also have you tested your network connection with `smtp.gmail.com` ? If so how did you do that exactly? How can you be sure everything is OK  with this connectio if you didnt check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a quite similar problem and it turned out the problem is caused by the mail port you are using (465). The Bluehost has blocked this port to discourage spam. Detailed information is available with the link:
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/500

It seems that maybe you either need to buy their service (which might still not be working, because the port is also blocked for a dedicated IP) or try to find a detour. In my own case, I changed SMTP to the E-mail address I use at the university since the website is just an intern thing.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Thank you!